# SourceTree on OSX: Clicking "Always Allow" bitbucket to use my password keychain has no effect

Tags: macos, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Every time I do a commit or pull on SourceTree, a popup comes up asking for my password. I click "always allow", but I still get prompted for my password every time via the same popup. Very annoying!

- I use SourceTree v Version 2.0.5.2 (2.0.5.2) on MAC OSX Yosemite
- I am using a git repository, hosted on BitBucket.

Somtimes the prompt to put in my password seems to come from OSX itself, without an option to always allow. And other times the popup comes from source tree, with the options, Allow, Aways All and Cancel.

This is what the popup looks like:
https://gyazo.com/200353a7cdeb69d2ea2969fd1a58b260

Comment: You might have to take this one to Atlassian support.

Comment: I am also having this problem. I found that my bitbucket password was repeated in keychain on my mac, and deleting the repeated passwords solved the problem, but only temporarily as the repeats came back.

Comment: FYI. The reason is very weird. If you take a close look at the `Keychain`, after you enter the password in `SourceTree`, there is indeed a password keychain being added to the `Keychain`. But in the following prompt alert for keychain access permission, once you click `Allow` or `Always Allow`, the newly added keychain is removed!!! That's why `SourceTree` is always asking for password and that's why `SourceTree` is always asking for keychain permission!!! I am currently using James McMahon's answer.

Answer (score 8):

Seems like this has been a [Sourcetree issue since 2012](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/34108/sourcetree-does-not-retrieve-user-name-and-password-from-keychain).

The SSH workaround that [Rizky Ariestiyansyah recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32017414/20774) works but another workaround is to switch to using your system's git.

This can be done by going to **SourceTree -> Preferences -> Git** and selecting "**Use System Git**".

Answer (score 6):

Seems there are more users get this bug, you should report this one to Atlassian.

I have advice to prevent this using SSH access, you can read how to use SSH in sourcetree [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=282173660)

Hope it help.